# Set the range of datetimecontrol

Tags: calendar, date-time, datetimecontrol

i have 2 DateTimeControl on my aspx page.

[image]

Is it possible to make that the second one begin at the selected date of the first one and make all the previous dates disabled?

I tried this on the code behind:

```
protected void StartDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EndDate.FirstDayOfWeek = StartDate.SelectedDate.Date.Day;
    //EndDate.FirstDayOfWeek = StartDate.SelectedDate.Day;
}
```

but this is not working...any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
protected void StartDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    EndDate.MinDate = StartDate.SelectedDate; // starting date as DateTime object
}
```

FirstDayOfWeek specifies which day has to be first in the popup display. For instance, sometimes a week has to start on sunday (int value 0) instead of saturday (int value 6).

Default value is 0, so the week will start on sunday by default.

Comment: I set the start date mindate to today's date but in the event handler
setting the mindate based on the selecteddate doesn't work

Comment: Is there any exception thrown?

Comment: no...just the event seems to be never launched

Comment: Can you add the code where you attach the event?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartDate.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
            EndDate.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
            StartDate.DateChanged += StartDate_DateChanged;
        }

        void StartDate_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EndDate.MinDate = StartDate.SelectedDate;
        }

Comment: Did you set the AutoPostBack property to true when creating the StartDate control?

Comment: God damn it i always forget it... thanks that was this little b**** ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your "DateChanged" event for the first control, you can set the "MinDate" property of the second control.  That is the property that prevents any dates prior to the set date from being selected.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol.mindate.aspx

Comment: I set the start date mindate to today's date but in the event handler
setting the mindate based on the selecteddate doesn't work